# Android phone application intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to launch the phone application on the phone as an intent

I am using this code

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.phone"));
```

but the function throws an nullpointer excaption so there is no launchable itent but how can i launch it to make the user watch the telephonylogs

Comment: What are "the telephonylogs"? And why do you think the user can watch them?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to answer my question thanks for your answers the didn't exactly met the thing I wanted but on base of tham I figured it out

I just had to call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

startActivity(intent);
```

to open only the phone application

Answer (score 2):

You need permissions for certain ones ...better off doing

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
     List<ResolveInfo> packs = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

and then you got the list of things you have permission for and then sort through this to launch.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code to dial a phone number with an intent, it might work for you.

```
String uri = "tel:" + phoneNumber.trim() ;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @FrankSposaro: There is no permission needed for `ACTION_DIAL`. You need one for `ACTION_CALL`. I suspect that this answer does not really address the OP's concern, though...

Comment: I don't want to make a call I just want to launch the phone application so the user can view the phone log so missed calls etc..

Answer (score -3):

I solved this problem previously, so here it is:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.htcdialer");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This will not work for pure Android, this solution is HTC firmware specific.