# Launching intent of certain android apps causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

There seems to be two problems that I am having trouble with.  The first case is when I launch the clock app and works perfectly, this seems to be the case when I launch most apps.

The second case is when I try to launch an activity such as the Phone activity.  When I go to get the Intent, getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.pname) returns null.  Is there a different way to get the Intent of the phone activity so that I can launch it in this case?

The third case is when I go to launch an activity such as the Camera activity.  It seems that I have to have the Camera activity already within my androidManifest.xml file to launch it but is there another way to go around this?  My app has the capibility to launch any app from its UI so I cannot add every single activity an android device has into my manifest file beforehand.  Thank you!

Java:

```
        Intent launchApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.pname);

            System.out.println(Intent of " + appName + ": + " " +launchApp);

            if(launchApp!=null){
                System.out.println("Permission granted to launch " + appName);
                startActivity( launchApp );
            }

            else{

                System.out.println("Permission not granted to launch " + appName);
            }
```

Logcat:

```
        08-07 09:38:57.031: I/System.out(1056): Intent of Clock: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.htc.android.worldclock/.WorldClockTabControl }
        08-07 09:38:57.041: I/System.out(1056): Permission granted to launch Clock
        08-07 09:38:59.783: I/System.out(1056): Intent of Phone: null
        08-07 09:38:59.783: I/System.out(1056): Permission not granted to launch Phone
        08-07 09:39:10.564: I/System.out(1056): Intent of Camera: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.camera/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity }
        08-07 09:39:10.574: I/System.out(1056): Permission granted to launch Camera
        08-07 09:39:10.574: D/AndroidRuntime(1056): Shutting down VM
        08-07 09:39:10.574: W/dalvikvm(1056): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2191)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4306)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at          java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2186)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     ... 11 more
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1565)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1539)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2919)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3025)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at com.worklight.androidnativeapp.AndroidNativeApp.appClicked(AndroidNativeApp.java:284)
        08-07 09:39:10.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to launch the camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

[How to launch the dialer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038286/android-phone-application-intent)

to launch a specific app you need to know the package name and the class name

```
try{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.example.app", "com.example.app.MainActivity");
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(e);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to just launch the activities just by using the Application Name or the Package Name?  Or do I have to hardcode in all the special cases such as the camera and dialer?

Comment: why do you need to launch them by application name, thats typically a bad idea

Comment: I am making a "favorites" app as a lead up to my actual application.  The user chooses a bunch of apps they want on their favorite screen, then when they go to the favorite screen they can press the icon of the app they want to launch.  Its bascially a glorified folder.  I have each app's name, packagename, and icon stored.  I have been using just the packageName to launch the app like above.  Is there a better way to be able to launch the apps, including the special cases such as the Camera app or the Phone app?

Comment: you need to know the package name and the class name to launch. see my edit

Comment: But the links you gave me are using a lot more information than just the package name and the class name.  I am just wondering if there is an easy fix or I should look into every app that causes a special case and hard code the ways to launch them

Comment: The links I provided are for launching the core android apps, not special case apps that other have made. Make sure the package name is correct when you are giving it to the intent which could be your problem